# ReactJs library for scan barcode

Tags: reactjs, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an USB Barcode Scanner device and i want a library in reactjs to check when the barcode are scanner and set it to the state.
I see some library such as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-barcode-scanner but this is only using the webcam.
I use library https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-scan-detection but it say document is undefined.
Anyone can help me with this. I want state barcode automacally set when barcode is deteced by device.
Many thanks

Comment: "I want state barcode automacally": mh, could you be more... clear ?

Comment: These usb barcodes scanner usually work like keyboards

Comment: I know USB Barcode scanner work like keyboards and ends with enter. My web have many state, and when the barcode is detected, i want barcodeResult update. Not choosing the input and check Barcode @YvesDaoust

Comment: Refer to the reader manual to see if there is an "event" mode.